# update query not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below query is throwing:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated.

```
update table1
set cust_line1_name = c.cust_line1_name
from table1 d
inner join dbo.table2 c
on c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id
and c.bus_grp_id = d.bus_grp_id
```

table1

```
 cust_line1_name - varchar(24)
```

table2

```
 cust_line1_name - nvarchar(140)
```

I checked whether any data which is having length greater than 24 is getting updated but there is no such data

```
SELECT LEN(c.cust_line1_name), c.cust_line1_name
from table1 d
inner join dbo.table2 c
on c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id
and c.bus_grp_id = d.bus_grp_id
WHERE  LEN(c.cust_line1_name)> 24
```

The above query is returing zero result. The issue is in SQL server 2008
Could someone help

Comment: I think you have missed a link between table1 and tables d and c

Comment: Do you have any triggers on this table?

Answer (score 3):

Converting to varchar from nvarchar is going to lose the data that isn't able to be converted. Anything in a foreign language from table2.cust_line1_name (nvarchar(140)) would not fit into your varchar 24

The correct course of action:

if table1 column has data:

1. Add a nvarchar(140) column to table 1
2. Copy data from current varcahar(24) column
3. Drop varchar(24) column
4. Rename the new nvarchar(140) column to old column name

If the table1 column has no data just drop it, and make your new column for populating with data from table2 the same size and data type as the one in table2.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the link between your update table (table1) and two tables in from clause:

Your query:

```
update table1
set cust_line1_name = c.cust_line1_name
from table1 d
inner join dbo.table2 c
on c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id
and c.bus_grp_id = d.bus_grp_id
```

You must add a WHERE condition to decide how you want to update your table1

For example, you can add

```
WHERE table1.id = d.id
```

Because d is the same table (table1)

Otherwise, how you have written your query, you have tried to put in a scalar field a list of rows (result of join between d and c table)

Comment: i added where still it is not working
update table1
set cust_line1_name = c.cust_line1_name
from table1 d
inner join dbo.table2 c
on c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id
and c.bus_grp_id = d.bus_grp_id
WHERE c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id

Comment: @Thomas: No, you're wrong, not c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id, but you must link table1.cust_id = d.cust_id

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1
set cust_line1_name = left(c.cust_line1_name, 24)
from table1 d, dbo.table2 c
Where c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id
and c.bus_grp_id = d.bus_grp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

make a change in the condition and then it works fine. 
Query is:

```
UPDATE table1
        SET cust_line1_name = c.cust_line1_name
        FROM table1 d INNER JOIN dbo.table2 c
        ON c.cust_nbr = d.cust_id
        AND c.bus_grp_id = d.bus_grp_id
        AND  LEN(c.cust_line1_name)<= 24
```